# multi client chat server throwing exceptions and not allowing connections after disconnect

Tags: java, exception, stream, connection, objectoutputstream

It's hard to fit it in the title but every time a client disconnects, a lot of exceptions are thrown and the server does not allow any more connections after the DC. Here is the error i get:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at ClientHandler.setupStreams(ClientHandler.java:34)
at ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:22)
```

Now i expect to get this exception because yea... The client closed the connection between the server and the client. but what i can't understand is why the client wont allow connections after the first disconnect. I am assuming that it breaks out of the while loop but why? Here is the code that takes the clients connection, accepts it and hands it off to the handler class:

```
public class ClientConnector
{
public static JTextField userText;
public static JTextArea chatWindow;
public static int Connections = 0;
public static Vector sendQueue = new Vector();
public static ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream> Streams = new ArrayList<ObjectOutputStream>();
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


public ClientConnector()
{

}

public static void runServer()
{
    try
    {   
        System.out.println("[Info] Attempting to bind to port 1337.");
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(1337);
        System.out.println("[Info] Bound to port 1337.");
        System.out.println("[Info] Waiting for client connections...");
        while(true)
        {
            Socket socket = serversocket.accept();
            new ClientHandler(socket).start();
            Connections += 1;


        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

That's fairly simple. Now for the code that handles the clients connection:

```
public class ClientHandler extends Thread
{
Socket ConnectedClient;
static ObjectOutputStream Output;
static ObjectInputStream Input;
public static boolean isError = false;
public static int updateCounter = 0;

ClientHandler(Socket socket)
{
    ConnectedClient = socket;
}

public void run()
{

    while(true)
    {
        setupStreams();//22
        WhileChatting();
    }
}

public void setupStreams()
{
    try 
    {
        if(isError == false)
        {
            Output = new ObjectOutputStream(ConnectedClient.getOutputStream());
            Input = new ObjectInputStream(ConnectedClient.getInputStream());//34
            ClientConnector.Streams.add(Output);
        }   
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        isError = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public static void WhileChatting()
{
    String Message = "";
    do
    {
        try
        {
            if(isError == false)
            {
                Message = (String)Input.readObject();
                for(int i = 0; i < ClientConnector.Streams.size(); i++)
                {
                    ClientConnector.Streams.get(i).writeObject(Message);
                    System.out.println(Message);
                }
            }

        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException CNFE)
        {
            isError = true;
            CNFE.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(EOFException eof)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < ClientConnector.Streams.size(); i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    Output.close();
                    Input.close();
                    ClientConnector.Streams.get(i).close();
                    ClientConnector.Streams.remove(i);
                    System.out.println("Connection lost");
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            isError = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    while(Message != "/disconnect");
}

public static void sendMessage(String message)
{
    try
    {
        if(isError == false)
        {
            Output.writeObject(message);
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException Ex)
    {
        isError = true;
        Ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void sendServerMessage(String message)
{
    int Limit = 0;
    try
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ClientConnector.Streams.size(); i++)
        {
            if(Limit == 0)
            {
                ClientConnector.Streams.get(i).writeObject("\247c[Server] \247d" + message);
                System.out.println("\247c[Server] \247d" + message);
                Limit = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void closeConnections()
{
    try
    {
        if(isError == false)
        {
            Output.close();
            Input.close();
            //ConnectedClient.close();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException Ex)
    {
        isError = true;
        Ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I have commented in the affected lines.
The error happens after the client disconnects. I don't know if it's the exception causing the while loop to break or weather it's something else. How can i make this code continute to allow incoming connectinos after the client disconnects. I  have tried debugging and using System.out.println. Thanks in advance to all who answered.

Answer (score 0):

> Now i expect to get this exception because yea... The client closed the connection between the server and the client.

No. This exception means that *you* closed the *`Socket`* and then tried to do further I/O on it. Nothing to do with the peer.

> but what i can't understand is why the client wont allow connections after the first disconnect.

There are numerous problems with your code.

1. You must use the same `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` for the life of the `Socket`, at both ends. At present you are creating a new pair, and adding them to the data structure, every time around the loop.
2. When you catch `EOFException` on one `Socket`, you are closing *all* the sockets. You should only close *one,* the one you got the exception from, and *then* you must break out of all loops and allow the thread to exit.
3. You should basically change your `while` loop from `while (true)` to `while (!isError)` and stop testing `isError` everywhere else. I would get rid of the `whileChatting` method and incorporate it into this while loop. And you don't need the inner `do` loop. You only need one loop that reads until EOS or a disconnect command.